# Laravel 5 timestamp not update right time

Tags: mysql, timestamp, laravel-5

After inserted record into database, `created_at` timestamp not display right time, it late 2h from server.... Also If i type into mysql `SELECT NOW()` it show right time, any idea what is problem?

Edit..

It take date from `Carbon` class... any idea how to change it?

Comment: I suspect timezones are at play here.

Comment: I now see it take date from `Carbon` class... any idea how to change it?

Comment: Why would you want to change it? It's the correct date. The MySQL `TIMESTAMP` field allows conversion to any timezone based on your MySQL session's timezone. You can change your app's timezone in the `config/app.php` file.

Comment: I need to be sync with server is it possible?

Comment: Do `SELECT @@system_time_zone;` and set your Laravel timezone to be the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default `timezone` for laravel is `UTC` which is located in `config/app.php` file.

If you want to change the `timezone` to your preferred `timezone`, choose your preferred `timezone` from [this list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) or from [this list](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp) and replace the `UTC` with your chosen timezone.

A few notes. As per the [comments here](https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=434-user-set-timezone/0), to be precise, the last 3 comments: You **should not** change the default values.

> Storing dates of different `timezones` in data source of a same
>   application (by changing the `timezone` in config for current user &
>   letting Laravel handle it from there on) is *just asking for trouble &
>   is a bad design*. You will lose data integrity. What will happen when a
>   user changes `timezone`? You'll update all the dates in the database for
>   that user?
>
> Store dates for all users as UTC (or any other timezone of your
>   choosing, just select one & stick to it). Laravel already uses the
>   excellent [Carbon  library](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), use it to convert dates from your
>   `timezone` (in which they're stored in DB) to users' `timezone` (which
>   you would store with in every user's settings) when you display the
>   dates.

Answer (score 1):

For the other people that also still have the wrong date/time after changing the config file:

My problem was in php in my vagrant box (Homestead).

To solve it I did:

First ssh into you vagrant box and then run this in the command line:

```
date
```

This should return something like "Mon Jul  3 13:48:52 CEST 2017". Check if this date/time is correct. If not do the following:

```
sudo ntpdate -b pool.ntp.org
```

This should update your system time. Check it again with the first command. If it is still not write you probably have to change your systems timezone. You can do this by running:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/localtime

sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam /etc/localtime
```

You can use any timezone you wish, I prefer "Europe/Amsterdam".

You can get other timezones [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)